# How do I preserve my Wendigo Prion?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, diseases, viruses

[Wendigo fever](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/167935/creating-a-plausible-wendigo-fever) is a Prion (credit goes to [SE is too politically correct](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/70058/se-is-too-politically-correct) for the idea) which is spread by the consumption of tainted meat. the main problem I have is to my knowledge Prions are solely spread though the consumption of tainted brain matter and as long as no one eats the brain the diseases should eventually die out so what I want to know is how do I stop that from happening?

NOTE: magic does not exist in my story

Comment: To make it clear, you are asking how to manage a prionic disease without curing it?

Comment: @Alexander i'm asking how to make sure it doesn't go extinct

Comment: What methods of preserving are applicable? Is having a folk tradition of eating brain acceptable?

Comment: Infectious prions don't only spread by infected brain matter. Scrapie and mad cow disease despite affecting the brain can be transmitted by infected body fluids or flesh in general. That greatly increases means of spread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Prions Can Be Spread In Multiple Ways**

[Fatal Familial Insomnia](https://rarediseases.info.nih.gov/diseases/6429/fatal-familial-insomnia) is a prion disease that is being spread genetically through a few families. It is completely fatal and resists all treatments.

[Chronic Wasting Disease](https://www.cdc.gov/prions/cwd/transmission.html) is a prion that has decimated populations of Cervids (deer family) across North America and Europe. It is spread through the exchange of body fluids.

It’s easy to justify the Wendigo Prion as being spread through saliva (bites) or through genetics when it is latent (a generational curse).

Comment: +1 purely for the latent curse.

Comment: could it be both?

Comment: @icewar1908 Potentially

Answer (score 4):

[Prions were found in sheep muscle too](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2004/05/prions-found-sheep-muscle). Lower concentration that in the brain, won't affect humans (as yet). Not much handwaving required to push it into higher concentrations and able to cross the species barrier.

Study [suggest prion diseases can be transmitted by blood transfusion too](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12388826)

Ah, btw, [scrapie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrapie) can be [transmitted by milk](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2011/01/110119191350.htm).
Also interesting in this FA: "The misfolded prions ... commonly accumulate in lymphoid tissues before invading the central nervous system"... so you can even imagine prey-populations evolving towards accumulating prions without getting them into their brain and developing the disease (sort of an asymptomatic carrier, Typhoid Mary but with prions).

Comment: Or, Wendigo Wendy, as the case may be.